Return value of 1 to 6 in cell A1 using excel 2021
I'm not sure if if I have to use IF formula or COUNT . Please forgive me as I am a newbie
I have cell A1 where I want the return answer to come but I have 6 arguments.
What I am trying to achieve is if I was to place any numbers at all in C1 E1 G1 I1 K1 M1 regardless of the figure higher of lower I would like A1 to populate the number 1 to 6.
Number 1 to be returned in A1 if C1 has a value
Number 2 to be returned in A1 C1 and E1 have values
Number 3 to be returned in A1 if C1 E1 and G1 have values
Number 4 to be returned in A1 if C1 E1 G1 and I1 have values
Number 5 to be returned in A1 If C1 E1 G1 I1 and M1 have values
Number 6 to be returned in A1 If C1 E1 G1 I1 K1 and M1 have values

Looks like a combination of IF() and ISBLANK(). Have fun :-)

Which version of excel are you using?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2021

Begin with #6 in an IF(here;else-portion), add #5 in an enclosed IF( ) in the else-portion, #4 in the else-portion of that, and so on...  OR
change the cell layout so the sensed cells are beside each other
and use any suitable *COUNT* -function.
e.g.
=COUNTIF(B1:G1,">0") might be one way - if your values always are greater than zero.
But might be better combined with IF( ) if you need e.g. the first five to be present for "5" as result.
=COUNT(A1:F1;"NOT(ISBLANK(A1))") - seems also work for cells A1:F1 having numeric values, but not strings/text.
With your cells:
=COUNTA(C1;E1;G1;I1;K1:M1) tells you how many cells have values, but not WHICH ONES, just as above.
You need the =IF( ;IF( ;...) construct.

I just got a bit more confused. So if I understand this you are recommending I move the columns and put them next to each other and write something like  CountIf A1(B1:G1),"1"6")) or something like that. Would it be possible if you could please give me an example  like an example formula. Sorry I'm am still learning this

Try this:
=IF(COUNTA(C1)>=1, 1, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1)>=2, 2, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1)>=3, 3, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1:I1)>=4, 4, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1:I1:K1)>=5, 5, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1:I1:K1:M1)>=6, 6, ""))))))

Have you tried it? I guess you haven't!

I'll try this when I get home and will let you know straight away . I'm still at work right now.. So will this work regardless of the numbers in the other cells. Example B1 is 2000 C1 is 5200 D1 is 1500 etc.. once I put any number as I go across the cells with A1 start counting 1 upwards

Error in formula. and even if corrected the result will not differ from a simple COUNTA(C1:G1) - pick away any single cell.

Would it work with COUNTA1(C1:G1)

A little explanation will make this a better answer. Use the EDIT button to explain what this formula is doing.

i Tried it but it did not work the reult i got was #Name? in A1 after trying the following formula =IF(COUNTA(C1)>=1, 1, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1)>=2, 2, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1)>=3, 3, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1:I1)>=4, 4, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1:I1:K1)>=5, 5, IF(COUNTA(C1:E1:G1:I1:K1:M1)>=6, 6,

I also tried moving the columns next to each other and using the formula    =IF(COUNTA(A4)>=1, 1, IF(COUNTA(A4:B4)>=2, 2, IF(COUNTA(A4:B4:C4)>=3, 3, IF(COUNTA(A4:B4:C4:D4)>=4, 4, IF(COUNTA(A4:B4:C4:D4:E4)>=5, 5, IF(COUNTA(A4:B4:C4:D4:E4:F4)>=6, 6, ""))))))    but it still won't count above 1

Basically all i am trying to do is  have a counter that tells me out of the 6 cells how many of them are populated regardless of figure inside them

Hi guys just wanted to thank you all for steering me in the right direction .  i got it working  by using the formula  =COUNTIFS(A4:F4,">0")
